# Also in PS6 foreach ($i in ((1,2)) ) {Write-Host $i} returns 2 strings in place of 1 array

Tags: powershell

When there are 2 elements

```
foreach ( $i in ((1,2),(3,4)) ) {Write-Host $i}
```

results in:

```
1 2
3 4
```

That's okay.

When there is 1 element

```
foreach ( $i in ((1,2)) ) {Write-Host $i}
```

results in:

```
1
2
```

This is ridiculous. It should result in:

```
1 2
```

I can not find a workaround. You?

Comment: That is `foreach` for: enumerate elements of collection. If you need array with one element, then you need to use unary comma: `(,(1,2))`.

Comment: @PetSerAl - Propose this as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: what is the point of this question? you already have an array. why do you need to return the exact same object?

Comment: You are right :). But in real Iive I do not know the length of the array. In case the length is 1 I get a wrong result. (Better to say: another result as espected to me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't remember exactly why but this works

```
foreach ( $i in (,(1,2)) ) {Write-Host $i}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Curious, but right according the docs. So in all cases when you not know the length of the array you have to use the 'unary comma'. Weird.

Comment: No, you don't need to know the length of the array ! foreach ( $i in (,(1,2),(3,4)) ) {Write-Host $i} Works ! You can always use the comma

Answer (score 0):

The `Write-host` cmdlet takes an input and sends a write command out to the host console.  That is always going to result in a new line per entry.

We could instead call `-join` on the input object and bypass the foreach, like so.

Imagine an array, from 1 to 4.  `1..4`

We can add `-join` and provide which character to join them on, we'll just join them with a space.

```
(1..4) -join ' '
```

If this doesn't help, let me know and I will make sure we find the right solution for you.

Comment: Well,  https://stackoverflow.com/users/1984242/miljbee already gives the right answer. Excuse me, but your suggestion is indeed a workaround.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I always like to highlight *why* people are encountering an issue, and to offer an alternative that might fit better in a real enterprise script.